# Are there different versions of Aronovsky's Black Swan?

Tags: alternate-version, black-swan

I recently watched Black Swan on TV. I've seen the movie in the theatre as well. I was surprised to discover that the nail skin peel scene wasn't in the TV broadcast.

Is it possible I watched a 'toned down' version of the film?

Comment: Edits of movies for different media, to conform to different durations, or other constraints such as 'toning down' are common. Some TV channels have strict regulations about sex, violence or language. Even without that, scenes may be cut to fit within an ideal time slot.

Comment: Wiat, isn't that censorship?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many movies are cut down for content and time to be shown on TV. Here's a description of the phenomenon, known as [Bowdlerization](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Bowdlerise).

Comment: Bowdlerization means altering or removing content so it is less rude, offensive, or otherwise inappropriate to the target audience. Cuts for time don't always fall into that category; sometimes they take out perfectly innocuous scenes because they are extraneous to the main plot, not because of content. Although in fairness, sometimes they are one and the same because there are a number of scenes that exist for shock value, not to further the main plot.